# Problem handling errors with FileSystemWatcher

Tags: vb.net, file-io, error-handling, filesystemwatcher

To start with it has been many years since I have done much programming, probably about 15 years, in fact VB 6 was still being taught then so I'm not up to date on anything and can get lost in what I'm reading but I am trying. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and trying to create a VB Windows Forms App that uses the FileSystemWatcher. Unfortunately the only solutions to my problem that I could find are in C#. I tried to transfer them to my app but couldn't get them to work. Actually Visual Studio wasn't happy with what I put in and wouldn't run at all, probably due to incorrect syntax.

This part of my little app is supposed to copy a file that another program creates, while the other program is running, and place the copy in another folder. It seemed simple, detect that the file had been changed and then copy the changed file. Well I came across a few problems.

The first problem is that if I create an empty file the code works most times with no problems but occassionally 2 copies of the file are created. I could live with that but.

If I replace the empty file with a larger file, the file that it is meant to copy, then it can make 3 or 4 copies and most times produces a messagebox telling me that it can't access the file because it is in use. The main program is also minimised to display the error message, which I don't want.

Even if my app is the only program running and I replace the watched file manually with the larger file I still get the file in use error, so I am assuming that the event has been triggered twice and one of them is the process that is using the file and causing the error.

If I tell the error message to cancel then my program continues and produces only 1 copy of the file. Which is what I do want.

The second problem is that the file being copied is also accessed by another program for a short period imediately after it has been changed and this also causes an extra few copies of it to be made and sometimes a file in use error message box appears, and again the main program is minimised to display the error message. I originally had other IO.NotifyFilters in place that weren't really necassary and thought that they may have been triggering the errors so I removed them, but it made no difference.

The most common error is that the file is in use but there has also been the odd "Unhandled exception has occured in your application. could not find file.". The only reason that I can think of for this error is that the file may have been renamed to a backup file and a new version created by the main program at the exact time my program tried to access it.

From what I have read the FileSystemWatcher can trigger multiple times and I presume that this is what is causing the duplicate copies from both problems.

I need my app to make only 1 copy without the error messagebox appearing as this program needs to run in the background with no user input. Essentially this part of my app is an external program to backup a file when the file changes because the main program changes this file often but only seems to back up the file every few hours.

The following code is what I have used but nothing that I have tried has caught the error so I removed the error event handler. This code was copied from something else that was similar and in C# then modified for my purpose. I thought that the {} were used for C# not VB but it seems to work and if I take them out it won't.

My code for the FileSystemwatcher is:-

```
            WatchFile = New System.IO.FileSystemWatcher With {
                .Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(strArkMapFileNamePath),
                .Filter = Path.GetFileName(strArkMapFileNamePath),
                .NotifyFilter = IO.NotifyFilters.LastWrite
            }

            ' add the handler to each event
            AddHandler WatchFile.Changed, New FileSystemEventHandler(AddressOf OnLastWrite)

            'Set this property to true to start watching
            WatchFile.EnableRaisingEvents = True
```

The event handler is:-

```
            Private Sub OnLastWrite(sender As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)

                'Copy the Save file to a new folder and rename it.
                My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(
                            strArkMapFileNamePath,
                            strBackupPath & "\" & strArkMapFileName & "_" & 
                DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy_hh.mm.ss") & ".ark",
                            Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs,
                            Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)

            End Sub
```

I added an error event handler after AddHandler WatchFile.Changed, New FileSystemEventHandler(AddressOf OnLastWrite) but that did nothing.

I tried to add an on error statement before the end sub and that did nothing either, I presume because the Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, caught the error first.

I got frustrated and tried to add a statement before the Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, but it didn't like that and I didn't expect it to work.

So how do I catch the errors before the FileSystemWatcher acts on the error?

I don't know what I am doing wrong so any help would be appreciated.
Also if anybody could offer code for what I need to do can it please be code for a Windows Forms App because I don't seem to have much luck in converting C# or anything else.

**Edit**
I have replaced the My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile with the File.Copy method as suggested and added a few extra bits..

Private Sub OnLastWrite(sender As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)

```
    'Verify that source file exists
    If File.Exists(strArkMapFileNamePath) Then

        'Copy the Save file to a new folder and rename it.
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 0 To 3

            Try
                ' Overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
                File.Copy(strArkMapFileNamePath, strBackupPath & "\" & strArkMapFileName & "_" & DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy_hh.mm.ss") & ".ark", True)
                i = 3

                ' Catch exception if the file was already copied.
            Catch copyError As IOException

                'If copy failed reset counter
                i += 1

            End Try

        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

Although this shouldn't be required because this is done before the FileSystemWatcher is enabled I have added an If statement to check that the files exists before attempting to copy the file.

I'm not entirely happy with the loop but I know under normal conditions that it's not going to be an endless loop.

Is there a way to just catch the specific errors that I would need to deal with or will it be fine the way it is?

I will probably still need to work out how to stop the FileSystemWatcher from sending more than 1 event or somehow make multiple events appear as 1.

The If statement was the last thing that I added and for some reason the program now seems to only make 1 copy and appears to be faster.

The other external program that accesses the file being copied must be slower to react than my program because now it displays a message that it's waiting until my program has finished copying the file.

My program is now performing as it was intended but I believe that it is just a matter of timing rather than the correct code.

Comment: I think that you may be able to simplify what can go wrong by using the [File.Copy method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy) instead of My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile.

Comment: I was thinking that another way to copy the file might make it easier to deal with the errors but I would still have to find a way to prevent the duplicates.

Comment: Could the File.copy being set to overwrite the file if it exists be what is preventing the duplicates? I thought that since I am adding the current time to the end of the filename that the names would be different.